# Linear Equation- Equation of a line passing through points

Tags: graphing-functions

What is the slope-intercept form of the equation of the line passing through the points (-1,-4) with an undefined slope?

Comment: is it my answer relevant or you meant different one?

Answer (score 0):

slope is   defined   as rise/run or $(y_2-y_1)/(x_2-x_1)$,in  your case  $x_1=-1$ and $y_1=-4$,which means that $x_2=-1$ and $y_2$ is equal to something else, this actual means that  line is straight line,in your case it is just $x=-1$.look please

http://www.purplemath.com/modules/slope.htm